# I am getting this error: actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm getting the error:

```
 Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

I've tried the solution in the following Stack Overflow question, but it didn't work:
[React-Redux: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765896/react-redux-actions-must-be-plain-objects-use-custom-middleware-for-async-acti)

action

```
export async function signupp(data){
    console.log('In signupp:');
    try{
        const request = await axios({
            method:'POST',
            url:'http://192.168.1.10:3003/users/signup',
            data:{
                email:data.email,
                password:data.password
            },
        }).then(response=>{
            console.log(response.data);
            return response.data
        }).catch( e => {
            console.log(e);
            return false
        }); 
        return {
            type:'signup',
            payload:request
        }
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        return false;  
    } 
}
```

reducer

```
export default function(state={},action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'signup':
            return {
                ...state,
                auth:{
                    email: action.payload.email,
                    password:action.payload.password
                }
            }    
    }
}
```

store

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);
const appRedux = () => (
    <Provider store = {createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>
)
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => appRedux);
```

BTW, I am getting the right response in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of the component, in the place where you call **signupp** function, you have **mapDispatchToProps** function as callback in connect function from react-redux lib, which is doing behind the hoods something like **dispatch(signupp())**(or maybe you are doing dispatch directly without react-redux lib).
According to redux API, this dispatch function expects to receive a plain object, but your signupp() function returns a promise(as you have async inside).

To solve this problem you can simply use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) middleware. Also you can see some examples in the redux docs section about [async actions](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#async-action-creators).

An alternative solution could be to move fetch logic to component and then dispatch just plain object with data that you received from the request.