# Running into error 'Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I've looked around threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765896/react-redux-actions-must-be-plain-objects-use-custom-middleware-for-async-acti) one, but it doesn't seem to help with my rather bizare issue.

Here are the 3 relevant methods.

```
const createFormData = post => {
    const {
        title,
        body,
        image
    } = post;

    const data = new FormData();

    data.append(
        "body",
        JSON.stringify({
            title,
            body,
            mediaType: image.type
        })
    );

    console.log(data); // prints

    return data;
};

const submitMedia = (data, replace) => async dispatch => {
    console.log('reached'); // never prints

    dispatch({
        type: SUBMITTING
    });

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            `http://${GATEWAY}:5000/api/uploads/single`,
            data
        );

        dispatch({
            type: SUBMISSION_PENDING
        });

        replace("NewSubmission", {
            name: "NewSubmission"
        });
    } catch (err) {
        // TODO test this
        dispatch({
            type: SUBMISSION_FAIL,
            payload: err.response.data
        });

        alert("Uh oh", "Something went wrong");
        console.log("Error caught", err);
    }
};

const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
        const post = {
            title,
            body,
            image
        };

        const data = createFormData(post);

        console.log('reached'); // never prints

        submitMedia(data, replace);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("err caught --> ", err);
    }
};
```

My program seems to build the form data properly, but it's almost as if it never exits `createFormData(post)` method. Not sure here to go from here, I've tried wrapping the method as a closure as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46766200/2891356) suggests, but no dice. I've even tried moving the async out of `handleSubmit()`, still nothing. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: First, are you sure you have properly installed and configured [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)? Then, could you show how you call `handleSubmit `?

Comment: I got it working by moving `createFormData` out of `client/src/utils/utils.js`. Also, I'd hope `redux-thunk` is properly configured.. I mean my other dispatched actions work just fine, just as does the method `submitMedia` (exported from `src/actions/media.js`) which is used by `handleSubmit`. Any idea why moving `createFormData` out of `utils.js` and directly writing it in the same file as `handleSubmit` got the program working? I decided to pass it off as something to potentially deal with later. I've been staring at the screen for 11 hours today.