# ReactJS - error passing an object to the action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

The goal is to get to send an object from my form to my action. (no async)

I keep getting **"Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."**

I have my action like this (I can console.log the productType and product,the data is coming to my action but I keep getting the console error mentioned above):

```
export function addProduct(productType, product) {
  switch (productType) {
    case 'survey':
      return {
        type: actions.ADD_SURVEY,
        payload: product,
      }

    case 'reward':
      return {
        type: actions.ADD_REWARD,
        payload: product,
      }

    default:
      return null
  }
}
```

In my component, I'm calling my action (data is the object from my form):

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

 const dispatch = useDispatch()

function onSubmit(data) {
  const productType = 'reward'
  dispatch(addProductAction({ productType, data }))
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46766200/10431732

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you dispatched an action, you passed an object to your action creator

```
dispatch(addProductAction({ productType, data }))
```

but your action creator takes 2 parameters, `productType` and `product`. Object you pass to your action creator is assigned to first parameter your action creator takes, i.e. `productType`.

Inside the action creator, you are using `productType` in `switch` statement. You expect it to be `string` but its an object. So your default case runs and `null` is returned from your action creator.

You can destructure the object passed to the action creator and then use `productType` in `switch` statement. Change your action creator as shown below

```
export function addProduct({productType, data}) {
  switch (productType) {
    case 'survey':
      return {
        type: actions.ADD_SURVEY,
        payload: data,
      }

    case 'reward':
      return {
        type: actions.ADD_REWARD,
        payload: data,
      }

    default:
      return null
  }
}
```

**OR**

you could just not pass an object to the action creator when dispatching an action

Change

```
dispatch(addProductAction({ productType, data }))
```

to

```
dispatch(addProductAction(productType, data))
```

Comment: Great explanation, I got it. Thanks Yousaf

Answer (score 1):

You need to fire the dispatch inside your action creator. Not the other way around.

You can do something like this:

```
import store from './path/to/store'

const dispatch = store.dispatch

export function addProduct(productType, product) {
  switch (productType) {
    case 'survey':
      dispatch({ type: actions.ADD_SURVEY, payload: product })

    case 'reward':
      dispatch({ type: actions.ADD_REWARD, payload: product})

    default:
      return null
  }
}
```

```
import { addProduct } from './path/to/actions'

function onSubmit(data) {
  const productType = 'reward'
  addProduct(productType, data)
}
```

If you want to use the dispatch hook in your React component, you must pass a plain object like `dispatch({ action: 'action', payload: data })`