# RTK Query query not refetching after mutation

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

On my api I have two mutations and strangely, one of them does trigger the refetch but the other doesn't and I have no clue why. Both mutations make their networks calls and changes are reflected in the server.

Here's my api definition.

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/react";
import Sample from "core/types/Sample";
import getApiURL from "core/utils/getApiURL";

export const lithologyApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: getApiURL() }),
  tagTypes: ["Samples"],
  endpoints: build => ({
    addSample: build.mutation<Sample, Sample>({
      query: sample => ({
        url: `lithology/add-sample`,
        method: "POST",
        body: sample,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["Samples"],
    }),
    getSamples: build.query<Sample[], void>({
      query: () => "lithology/get-samples",
      providesTags: ["Samples"],
    }),
    deleteSample: build.mutation<void, number>({
      query: id => ({ url: `lithology/delete-sample/${id}`, method: "DELETE" }),
      invalidatesTags: ["Samples"],
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useAddSampleMutation,
  useGetSamplesQuery,
  useDeleteSampleMutation,
} = lithologyApi;
```

I don't know if it's relevant but the mutation that succesfully invalidates (`addSample`) it's in a different component, while the one that doesn't (`deleteSample`) it's in the same (I've already tried moving it to another component and it didn't work anyways).

Comment: Hmm. Generally: change the import to `"@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react"` but that won't solve the problem. Are all of these really in one `createApi` call or did you simplify that for the Stackoverflow question? Also, just to make sure: the middleware is registered?

Comment: Yes, that's all there is for that createApi call and yes, the middleware is registered. I mean, the `deleteSample` mutation callback makes the network request, it just doesn't trigger the invalidation for `getSamples` (which `addSamples` does).

Comment: If the middleware were not registered, it would still make the network request, but not trigger invalidation, that's why I was asking.

Comment: Do you get a completely empty response back? And can you check if your mutation actually goes into an `isError` state? I have an assumption.

Comment: Because I was in a hurry, I ended doing things how I was doing them before, so I don't have that code available anymore. I'll definitely try it on with any new project I have and thank you very much for helping :)

Comment: In my case it was case mentioned by @FooBar, tho I had to add [thunk before this middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62302377/17507134)

Answer (score 2):

So, just to give an answer here so that someone else can maybe use it:

I assume that your `deleteSample` endpoint was giving an empty response. Per default, `fetchBaseQuery`'s `responseHandler` is set to `json`, so it tries to `JSON.parse` an empty string - and crashes with an unhandled error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Now, `invalidateTags` is only called on success and for *handled* errors, but not in the case of an unhandled error, since that would lead to all kinds of inpredictable behaviour in case your `invalidateTags` was not an array, but a function.

Long story short: In your request, set `responseHandler` to `text` or a custom function.

Also, always read errors - when you read that error above getting back from your hook, it should already become pretty obvious :)

Comment: This sounds like the most likely case, however I don't remember ever seeing any unhandled error on console. I'll try testing if this is the case and I wonder if it might be useful to change parts of the question to match more specifically the problem, so people find it easier.

Comment: Even unhandled, it would end up in the `error` field of the hook, not on the console.

Comment: This helped me on my issue on using SWAPI's wookie format. Indeed, the `responseHandler` does a `JSON.parse` under the hood. And in my case, I am using ngrx-rtk-query for my ng project. When the handler fails to parse the data, error is caught internally and `transformResponse` is simply not invoked.

Comment: Updating to Redux Toolkit 1.6.1 should give you a much more descriptive error and any unhandled error will also be printed to the console.

Comment: Thank you, this really solved my issue! Turns out my mutation was expecting a response from the server with a generics like <Post, Post>, so changing it to <void, Post> resolved the issue, since API doesn't provide any response :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was related to not adding the [middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview#configure-the-store) to `configureStore`.

```
export const lithologyApi = createApi({
// ....
});

const store = configureStore({
    // ....

    // Adding the api middleware enables caching, invalidation, polling,
    // and other useful features of `rtk-query`.
    middleware: [
        lithologyApi.middleware,
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the next function to the file and replace the `providedTags` in  `getSamples` query function.

```
const providesTags = (result: ReportPinsResponse | undefined) => {
  if (result && result.items) {
    const { items } = result;
    return [...items.map(({ id }) => ({ type: CACHE_TAGS.Samples, id }))];
  }

  return [CACHE_TAGS.Samples];
};
```

And then your query mutation will look like:

```
deleteSample: builder.mutation<void, number>({
    query: (id) => ({
      url: `lithology/delete-sample/${id}`,
      method: 'DELETE',
    }),
    invalidatesTags: (_, __, id) => [{ type: CACHE_TAGS.Samples, id }],
    }),
```

```
enum CACHE_TAGS {
  Samples = 'Samples',
}
```